# matlab: store vector output in matrix/cell

Tags: matlab, matrix

The result of solving a polynom equation is a 1x2 vector or a 1x1 in some instances. I am trying to store all solutions for equations with different coefficients. so some solutions are just 1x1 vectors. how can i store these efficiently?

```
n = 1;
%sol = zeros(size(coef));  %create solution matrix in memory
sol = {};

while n < size(coef,2)
        sol(n) = roots(coef(:,n));

end
```

"Conversion to cell from double is not possible."
error.

coef is coefficient matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there!

In order to store the vectors as cells in the cell array, use curly braces {} during their assignment:

```
sol(n) = {roots(coef(:,n))};
```

or alternatively:

```
sol{n} = roots(coef(:,n));
```

That way, the vectors/arrays can be of any size. Check [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html) link for more info about accessing data in cell arrays.

Also, don't forget to increment `n` otherwise you will get an infinite loop.

Whole code:

```
n = 1;
%sol = zeros(size(coef));  %create solution matrix in memory
sol = {};

while n <= size(coef,2)
        sol(n) = {roots(coef(:,n))};
n = n+1
end
```

Comment: well it runs but now it get a matrix full of 1x1 cell arrays with no method of accessing the desired values. preferably i would have a matrix of vectors of some sort (2x1), easy to iterate over

Comment: the goal of cell arrays is to store data of different sizes. If you have 2x1 and  1x1 data you can't use a regular array to store them all

Comment: I understand that, so I get [2x1] as one of the solutions but that doesnt tell me about the value, accessing them with {} as well I suppose? the solutions are rounded to integers in the vectors how do i extract values of 15 digits (the max) ?

Comment: Ok glad you found out! Cheers